# Обновление версии Android приложения - как?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Залил в PlayMarket приложение, доработал его, хочу залить ОБНОВЛЕНИЯ. Создал новый APK файл программы где в манифесте указал:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.evgeniy.dailyspending"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.2">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

При загрузке АРК файла выдает ошибку "APK-файл с кодом версии 1 уже существует. Используйте другой код."
Как обновить?

Comment: Вы уверены, что внутри вашего нового .apk-файла в AndroidManifest.xml указано `android:versionCode="2"`? Проверяли это?

Comment: Выложите полный код манифеста (без комментариев)

Comment: Да, еще раз сохранил, создал APK файл и попробовал залить, ошибка так же.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, с полным Манифестом

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko не помню чтобы у меня возникали проблемы из-за кеширования манифеста, но мало ли - проверить, если вы не проверяли, думаю стоит. Посмотрите манифест в уже собранном .apk-файле. Если внутри всё же версия кода 2, то можно будет думать над проблемой дальше.

Comment: Опа, не меняет, из-за чего?

Comment: <manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    package="ua.zaychenko.eugene.expenses"
    platformBuildVersionCode="25"
    platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1">

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko я вижу три варианта: либо вы меняете значения значение в каком-то другом манифесте, либо файл манифеста закешировался, либо новый .apk так и не собрался (например, из-за какой-то ошибки при сборке). Нужно определить какой из трёх вариантов является причиной в вашем случае.

Comment: Манифест нужный, это точно, АРК собирается и проблем нет. Что значит "файл манифеста закешировался" и как с этим бороться? 
Единственное, я переименовывал пакет, но ошибок не было. И когда в первый раз заливал приложение строчки с версией не было (ставится по у молчанию первая, как я понял)

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko под кешированием в данном случае я подразумеваю ситуацию, при которой файл был изменён, а при сборке по-прежнему используется его старая версия. В случае с .java-файлами, например, я такое частенько наблюдаю при смене значения константы. Помогает очистка и сборка проекта заново. Справедливо ли это по отношению к манифесту - не знаю. Попробуйте очистить и пересобрать проект.

Comment: Создал новый проект, перезалил все в него, установил версию 2, собрал арк - а в нем все равно  версия 1!!!! Что за...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Версию надо менять НЕ В МАНИФЕСТЕ а в файле build.gradle !!!!!!

Comment: Либо убрать номер версии из _build.gradle_. Учитывая что он приносит  мне одни огорчения, я с ним не связываюсь. Буду знать.

Comment: То что вы с ним не связываетесь, очень плохо ибо это очень полезный, мощный инструмент, через который происходит все сборки включая обычного структурирования проекта и заканчивая огромных возможностей пребилдовых скриптов, это инструмент с которого начинается работа опытных разработчиков, я могу посмотреть в гредл и структуру либ и сказать что этот проект из себя представляет

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо проверить versionCode в двух местах, это build.gradle внутри модуля (приложения), и в файле манифесте этого модуля. Если в Gradle скрипте его нет то он будет Overide(переопределен) в Android manifest и копироваться оттуда. В другом случае приоритет будет конечно у Gradle, так как скрипт является сборкой и управляет Build.properties, эти данные можно получить раньше. Плохой практикой является оставлять оба параметра (как скорей всего у вас в примере), так как вам необходимо отслеживать их в 2 местах. 
Хорошей практикой является указать versionCode только в gradle, более того использовать build.properties для формирования данных для ui , чтоб показать системную информацию например, тогда все сведётся к единственному  необходимому изменению.
----------}